# Gradle - change Begin/End Token when using ReplaceTokens

Tags: gradle

I have some files that need token replacement .. instead of the default single @, they use double @'s ... So I need stuff like: @@replaceme@@  .. replaced.

Ant's ReplaceTokens filter allows you to set it using BeginToken / EndToken .. Though I'm not sure how to configure it in my example:

```
copy{ 
  into something
  from somethingelse
  filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [])  
}
```

How can I change the above code to replace correctly work with double @@ tokens instead of single ones?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's easy to change the delimiters - just add named parameters `beginToken` and `endToken` to the `filter` method call. However, Ant's `ReplaceTokens` only support single-character delimiters. A quick web search didn't turn up an Ant `FilterReader` that supports arbitrary multi-character delimiters out of the box. An alternative is to code this yourself, either by implementing `FilterReader` or by using the free-form [filter](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:filter(groovy.lang.Closure)) method.

Comment: Nice .. Missed the lack of support for non single-character delimiters that's probably why my code wasn't working.

Answer (score 12):

I was in a similar (not exact) situation. Had to process test property resources which were in maven format. i.e '${}' format.

When I moved onto gradle, processTestResources task did not replace the values in ${}. This is because of the same reason that it uses '@' single char delimited. I found a hack to achieve what I wanted.

```
configure(tasks.processTestResources) {
    include '**/*.properties'
    filter(ReplaceTokens,
            tokens: ['$':'={'], beginToken : '=', endToken : '{')
    filter(ReplaceTokens,
            tokens: [project.properties], beginToken : '{', endToken : '}')
}
```

Comment: Totally hack-y and totally works! I'm using **/\*@TOKEN@\*/** formatted tokens so that they're valid anywhere in CSS/JS and the following does the trick: 

`filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['*':'@'], beginToken: '/', endToken: '@')`

`filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['*':'@'], beginToken: '@', endToken: '/')`

Answer (score 9):

The other answers seem to be old and report that you can't use multi-character token delimiters. But I have found that not to be the case anymore with Gradle 2.14.1

```
copy{ 
  into something
  from somethingelse
  filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [map], beginToken : '@@', endToken : '@@')
  // or, maven prop stle:
  // filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [map], beginToken : '${', endToken : '}')

}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since whatever version made the change that allowed non-single character delimeters!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution. Use Ant copy task instead of Gradle copy task.

```
task copyWithMultiCharTokenMark << {
    ant.copy(todir: 'copy_into_dir') {
        fileset(dir: 'copy_from_dir')
        filterset(begintoken:'@@', endtoken:'@@') {
            filter( token:'replaceme', value:'Am I replaced?')
        }
    }
}
```

I found this way while searching workaround for file encoding issue with copy task.

- https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1267
- http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/How-do-I-configure-a-file-encoding-for-the-CopyTask-with-the-filter-for-replacing-tokens-td3311705.html