# can gradle be used to replace a value in spring context?

Tags: spring, properties, replace, gradle, profile

I have two different profiles for a webapp: "test" and "dev", then I have 2 folders with files, `/opt/myApp/dev` and `/opt/myApp/test`.

I need to build my App, sending parameters to gradle, in order to define paths depending of the profile.

In my spring application-context.xml I have this:

```
 <bean id="myBean" class="com.myClass">
        <property name="locations" value="file:/opt/myApp/${profile}"</property>
 </bean>
```

Will be fine if I cant make something like this:

```
 gradle build -Pprofile
```

And a gradle script do the work

I looked in the documentation and stackoverflow, I found about filters. But I couldn't make it work.

I am trying  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532632/gradle-string-replacement-no-placeholders) and other similars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a cleaner way, but how about something like:

application-context.xml:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.myClass">
    <property name="locations" value="file:/opt/myApp/@profile@"</property>
</bean>
```

build.gradle:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.*
apply plugin: 'java'

if (! hasProperty("profile")) {
  ext.profile = "dev"
}

processResources {
  filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [profile: profile])
}
```

Then invoke it like:

```
gradle -Pprofile=test
```

Comment: Thanks man, thats work.
I was missing the `import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.*`.  Now I just have to change the begin and endToken.
 [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322148/gradle-change-begin-end-token-when-using-replacetokens)